# How socket family functions can work with different types of structures?

Tags: c, sockets, struct, parameters, parameter-passing

How socket functions, connect, bind, accept, etc, can work with different types of structures with different sizes? For example, connect() takes a struct sockaddr as its second argument, but it is OK to pass a struct sockaddr_in or struct sockaddr_in6 as well, provided that the third argument socklen_t namelen, has the right value. But actually, these structures have different format:

```
struct sockaddr {
  uint8_t      sa_len;
  sa_family_t  sa_family;
  char         sa_data[14]; 
};

struct sockaddr_in {
  uint8_t         sin_len;   
  sa_family_t     sin_family; 
  in_port_t       sin_port;   
  struct in_addr  sin_addr;    
  char            sin_zero[8]; 
};

struct sockaddr_in6 {
  uint8_t         sin6_len; 
  sa_family_t     sin6_family; 
  in_port_t       sin6_port; 
  uint32_t        sin6_flowinfo; 
  struct in6_addr sin6_addr; 
  uint32_t        sin6_scope_id;
};

struct sockaddr_storage {
  uint8_t      ss_len; 
  sa_family_t  ss_family;
      /* implementation-dependent fields */
};
```

These structures seem to have nothing in common (actually, only sin_len and ss_family, but sin_len itself is not portable and not all platforms support it), but we use same function for all of them. I don't think these functions merely depend on the third argument (namelen), because depending on the actual size of an object, to determine its type, is non-portable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one thing the structures have in common is that they all start with a `family` field (the `len` field is not present on all platforms) that is at the same offset and size for all `sockaddr_...` types.  That field, coupled with the socket's actual address type (established by `socket()` or `accept()`) is enough for each function to validate the size and format of any `sockaddr` you pass in, and thus they can report errors on mismatches.

`sockaddr_storage` is designed to be large enough in size to hold any other `sockaddr_...` struct type.  You can pass a `sockaddr_storage` to any of the functions.  You can type-cast it to any other `sockaddr_...` type.  As such, you can type-cast a `sockaddr_storage` based on its `ss_family` field.  For input, type-cast to the desired `sockaddr_...` type and populate its fields as needed, including `family`.  For output, look at the `ss_family` field and then type-cast to the appropriate `sockaddr_...` type as needed.

For example, if the socket's address type is `AF_INET` (IPv4), `connect()` requires the `sockaddr` buffer to be in `sockaddr_in` format and the `namelen` parameter to be at least `sizeof(sockaddr_in)`.  Likewise, `accept()` populates the `sockaddr` buffer with data in `sockaddr_in` format and the `addrlen` parameter must be at least `sizeof(sockaddr_in)`.

For `AF_INET6` (IPv6), replace `sockaddr_in` with `sockaddr_in6` instead.

The same applies to the other functions.

In general, the size of your `sockaddr` buffer must be large enough to hold the correct `sockaddr_...` struct that belongs to the socket's address type.  Functions that accept an address as input (`connect()`, `bind()`, `sendto()`) require the buffer to be formatted in the correct `sockaddr_...` format.  Functions that return an address as output (`accept()`, `recvfrom()`) will format the data using the appropriate `sockaddr_...` type.

Answer (score 1):

It is in part a legacy from pre-standard C, when things were more lax.  For example, the code predates function prototypes.

Actually, those structures all have 2 things in common:

1. The first field is a `uint8_t` and gives the length of the structure.
2. The second field is a `sa_family_t` that identifies which structure type is in use.

The C standard says:

> #### §6.5.2.3 Structure and union members
>
> ¶6 One special guarantee is made in order to simplify the use of unions: if a union contains
> several structures that share a common initial sequence (see below), and if the union
> object currently contains one of these structures, it is permitted to inspect the common
> initial part of any of them anywhere that a declaration of the completed type of the union
> is visible. Two structures share a common initial sequence if corresponding members
> have compatible types (and, for bit-fields, the same widths) for a sequence of one or more
> initial members.

Taking minor liberties, if you consider the type passed to the socket functions to be a pointer to a union of the various separate types, then you can see that the code can access those first two fields to determine what type is actually in use.

I'm not convinced that this design is what you'd come up with now if you were redesigning the sockets system from scratch, but it can still be made to work.

Comment: On that same note, the original socket functions were designed at a time when IPv4 was the only address type available, and was represented by `sockaddr` itself. When other address types became available later on, the function prototypes could not be changed, but the original `sockaddr` became `sockaddr_in` and `sockaddr` became opaque. The prototypes continue to take `sockaddr*` pointers as parameters to this day, but at last the functions are smart enough to recognize the `family` field and act accordingly.